# Need to take two fields from one model and use it as foreign key for a new model using django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

**Model 1**

```
class Users(models.Model):

    employee_name = models.CharField(max_length=210)
    dob=models.DateField(max_length=8) 
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254,default=None) 
    pancard=models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None)
    aadhar=models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None)
    personal_email_id=models.EmailField(max_length=254,default=None)
    phone = PhoneField(blank=True)
    emergency_contact_no=models.IntegerField(default=None)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    relation=models.CharField(max_length=25,default=None)
    blood_group=models.CharField(max_length=25,choices=BLOOD_GROUP_CHOICES,null=True)
    joining_role=models.CharField(max_length=250,choices=JOINING_ROLES_CHOICES,null=True)
    billable_and_non_billable=models.CharField(max_length=250,choices=BILLABLE_and_NON_BILLABLE_CHOICES,default='Billable')
    joining_date=models.DateField(max_length=15,null=True)
    relieving_date=models.DateField(max_length=15,null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee_name
```

**Model 2**

```
class Consolidated(models.Model):
    
    emp_name=models.ManyToManyField(Users,related_name="employee_name+")
    proj_name=models.ManyToManyField(Project)
    custom_name=models.ManyToManyField(Client)
    Cons_date=models.ManyToManyField(Add_Timelog)
    bill_no_bill=models.ManyToManyField(Users,related_name="billable_and_non_billable+")
    hour_spent = models.ManyToManyField(Add_Timelog,related_name="hour_spent")
    
    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.emp_name)
```

I need to take the value updated on the "employee_name" and "billable_and_non_billable" field in the "User" model to "emp_name" and "bill_no_bill" field in "Consolidated" model. Will it be possible to take two fields as foreign key from one model to another. I'm new this django kindly help me if there is any possible ways.

Comment: There are no "composite primary keys/foreign keys" in Django. But normally you do not need these. Why does your `Consolidated` has so much `ManyToManyField`s?

Comment: Yes, Consolidated model API is a combination of 4 to 5 models API. That's why there are so much ManytoManyfield in that model. I have taken single single field from one one model and grouped that as a Consolidated model.

Comment: but it is very odd that these are `ManyToManyField`s and not `ForeignKey`s, especially since you use `str(self.emp_name)` as `__str__` and this thus refers to *multiple* `User`s, not a single user.

Comment: can you please help me out to do it in a proper way?. Thanks in advance

Comment: @vinothkumor: well you should explain *what* you try to model. Not that much *how*.

Comment: Yeah sure. I have four models say(User, client, project, Add_timelog). So, basically four API created seperately. I need a final "consolidated" model API which should display the values which we enter in the mentioned four models. I don't need all fields from all four models, I need only the values of fields for ex: form 'User' model need 'Employee name' field and from 'Client' model need 'client name' and from 'project' model need 'project name' and from 'Add_timelog' model need 'Date and hour' field. I need to display the values from them in a seperate API as a view.

Comment: As per my above code i can take the values and display it in a seperate API and table view. But i cant able to take two values fields from one model as i need it to display that in my "Consolidated" model. Please let me know if this explanation doesnt satisfy you, i will be happy to assist you more.